# Android Studio Appcompat conflict with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

i try import eclipse project to android studio and get this error

```
Error:(1) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "divider" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "background" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "backgroundSplit" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "navigationMode" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "displayOptions" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "title" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "subtitle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "icon" has already been defined
```

and i figure it out appcombat is conflict with actionbarsherlock. i try to migrate from abs to appcombat but. seems the project i got is hardcoded with actionbarsherlock. so its imposible for me. i decide to exclude the appcombat so the actionbarsherlock work without conflict.

here's my gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.myapps.android"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_5
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':menudrawer')
    compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/tagsoup-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/wordpresscom-android-rest-v0.0.3.jar')
}
```

its bit oldy project, but its all i need. in these gradle. i dont see the appcombat depencies. so how to exclude appcombat from android studio?

Comment: why would you need both ?

Comment: Just fyi, you don't need the `support-v4` dependency twice in your dependencies list.

Comment: i just figure it out that appcombat is inside compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3' too lol. im totaly new for this. and i just remove "compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'" line and still got error. i just google and find that appcombat is inside "com.google.android.gms:play-services" too. so how to exclude appcombat from inside "com.google.android.gms:play-services" ?

Comment: If you exclude it, you'll probably run into issues. It's a dependency for a reason. ABS is deprecated because its obsolete and AppCompat replaces it, so you really should look harder at migrating.

Answer (score 1):

ActionBarSherlock was [[DEPRECATED]](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)

remove ActionBarSherlock from your project and use Appcompat library to have actionBar on old versions.

appcompat usage:

in your Gradle file add:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

in style file set appcompat as your parent theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

extent your activity from AppCompatActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```