# Error after adding dependencies to Action Bar Sherlock in Android Studio 1.2.2

Tags: android

Okay, I know this question has been asked a lot. I've tried several methods posted in SO. None seems to work for me.

So, here's how I do it. I add this line of code inside dependencies in my gradle files:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'

here is my Gradle view:

```
dependencies 

{
    compile project(':pagerSlidingTabStrip')


    compile project(':circleImageView')
    compile project(':appRater')
    compile project(':urlImageViewHelper')
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':slidinglibrary')
    compile project(':photoView')
    compile project(':library_pull')
    compile project(':droidparts')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.0'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.19.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.19.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/java-websocket-1.3.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/libphonenumber-5.2v1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2-with-sources.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ActionBarSherlock was DEPRECATED**

check my answer here to Replace actionbarSherlockwith AppCompat:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32505440/2943501